# execute multiple create view statements in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to create multiple views in one query in Snowflake?

I keep getting error when I try this -

```
create or replace view forecast_view as
select * from forecast
where variable = 'Name'
    
go

create or replace view demand_view as
select * from demand
where variable = 'Name'
```

Error:

```
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 5 at position 0 unexpected 'go'.
```

I also tried this -

```
create or replace view forecast_view as
select * from forecast
where variable = 'Name';

create or replace view demand_view as
select * from demand
where variable = 'Name';
```

but it only executes the first create view statement.

Comment: Is your query a stored procedure?

Comment: Where are you trying to execute these statements?

Comment: I was executing them in Snowflake web app and also from Python. I got around to it in Snowflake by selecting run both queries in the Run button. In python, I just run them as separate queries. Didn't make much of a difference so just ran them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "go" command in SnowFlake:

[SnowFlake Commands](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql-all.html)

[Executing Multiple SQL Statements in a Stored Procedure](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Executing-Multiple-SQL-Statements-in-a-Stored-Procedure)